# Jquery Fullcalendar Struts2 Event as Json

Tags: jquery, struts2, fullcalendar

I have successfully fetched my data from database but got some problem at displaying EVENTS DOES NOT SHOW IN CALENDAR but my query runs in console.

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'DoctorSchedule!onLoad',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    start: start.unix(),
                    end: end.unix()
                },
                success: function(event) {
                    var events = [];
                    events.push({
                        title: event.title,
                        start: event.start,
                        end: event.end
                    });
                    callback(events);
                }
            });
        },
```

Comment: Should we guess what problem did you get?

Comment: @AleksandrM im sorry :)

Comment: What data do you get in `success` handler? Does you function goes into the `success` at all?

Comment: **_ 1412583735032
end 1415491200
start 1411862400**

Comment: got my params as json but it doesnt draw event on calendar :D

Comment: If you print `event` what do you see? Are you sure you receive a correct json and can get properties from it (like `event.title`)?

Comment: @AleksandrM seems i got it wrong im getting following error on success page **Invalid action class configuration that references an unknown class named [DoctorScheduleS]**

Comment: @AleksandrM finally figured it out thank you , you helped me a lot than you think.

Comment: ;) BTW you can answer your own question to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by using array

```
 var events = [];
                   var calendarlst = doc.hmi_alldays;

                   for (var int = 0; int < calendarlst.length; int++) {

                    events.push({
                           title: calendarlst[int].title,
                           start: calendarlst[int].start,
                           end: calendarlst[int].end
                       });
                }
```